# What is the correct translation for "content curation"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Wikipedia defines content curation as:

> (...) the process of collecting, organizing and displaying information relevant to a particular topic or area of interest. Services or people that implement content curation are called curators.

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curation_de_contenu) says "curation de contenu"  but it doesn't feel right (at least to me). Would "gestion de contenu" or "organisation de contenu" be better suited? Anything better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Une bonne intuition et un bon réflexe, et pour moi aussi ça sonne faux. L'article *Wikipédia* nous avertit qu'il s'agit d'une *ébauche*, et sa section [*discussion*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:Curation_de_contenu) remet en doute sa pertinence. L'expression « *curation de contenu* » ne génère aucun [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curation%20de%20contenu&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) (ni même en [anglais](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=content%20curation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) ; mais on ne sait pas si le [corpus](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) intègre 2012 et il n'inclut pas 2012-2015). *Larousse* en ligne n'a pas le mot *curation*, ni *FranceTerme*. Au *TLFi*, si le contenu était malade, peut-être que la [*curation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/curation) en constituerait le remède par un [*curateur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/curateur), pourrait-on dire. [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/curation) a le mot *curation* avec un contexte : « *Mise à jour manuelle d’une base de données, d’un site Internet, voire du web* ». On étaye par une citation contenant l'expression « *curation de contenus en ligne* » tirée d'un *blog* de 2012.

On a au *Termium*, plus traditionnel (le musée, les archives), la «  [**conservation du contenu**](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=CONTENT%20CURATION) », un peu différent de ce qu'on recherche ; mais ils ont le « [*conservateur de contenu*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=CONTENT%20CURATOR) » pour le titre en contexte (*content curator* ; surtout [*commissaire*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=commissaire&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) en France pour *curator*). Au *GDT* on a identifié la [*curation de contenu*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26507071), comme un terme déconseillé (« *Le terme anglais curation est formé à partir de curator. Aussi, le calque curation (de contenu) est à éviter.* », *GDT*). On suggère plutôt « **édition de contenu** » et « **organisation de contenu** », usuels et adéquats, tel qu'on en avait l'intuition en question.

Comment: curation est effectivement extra-terrestre ! édition et organisation sont tout à fait naturels !

Answer (score 3):

You can  use one of these:

- *curation de contenu*
- *aggrégation de contenu*

As mentioned in the link you provided, the French word *curation* emanates from the English word curation which itself takes its origin from the Latin word *curare*.

*Curation* appeared in French language by the end of 2010 (as stated through your link).

> Would "gestion de contenu" or "organisation de contenu" be better
>   suited? Anything better?

The short answer is no.

Detailed answer:

You need to understand the concepts hidden behind the two notions of **content curation** and **content management** (*gestion de contenu*). I am not going to reproduce the definitions you have already read, but I want to mention the main difference between them instead:

- content curation: the content you share is not yours.
- content management: the content is produced by yourself.

As for *organisation de contenu* it can not replace in any case *curation de contenu*, *gestion de contenu* or *aggrégation de contenu* of which *organisation* is just a part.

Conclusion:

You must use curation de contenu or aggregation de contenu.

Important [note](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curation_de_contenu#Curation_vs._agr.C3.A9gation) to read:

> La différence essentielle entre curation et agrégation réside dans le
>   fait de choisir les contenus proposés aux internautes pour leur donner
>   du sens et non pas de se contenter d'une collecte de liens sans
>   contextualisation. D'autres[Qui ?] ne voient pas de différence de
>   fonction mais évitent le mot curation (curateur désigne, en France, un
>   mandataire de justice !). Ils utilisent plus volontiers Agrégation
>   Web.

Answer (score 0):

Redistribution de contenu ? 
Sélection de contenu ?